# "No token" error on not protected route in angular4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I get a really weird bug with routing in angular 4 and i have no idea how to solve it.
error message is:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No token Error: No token
>       at viewWrappedDebugError (/vendor.bundle.js:128545)
>       at callWithDebugContext (/vendor.bundle.js:133596)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (/vendor.bundle.js:132903)
>       at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:129994)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:123411)
>       at ViewContainerRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ViewContainerRef_.createComponent
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:130196)
>       at RouterOutlet.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.RouterOutlet.activateWith
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:154164)
>       at ActivateRoutes.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:153303)
>       at /vendor.bundle.js:153254
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at viewWrappedDebugError (/vendor.bundle.js:128545)
>       at callWithDebugContext (/vendor.bundle.js:133596)
>       at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (/vendor.bundle.js:132903)
>       at ComponentFactory_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactory_.create
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:129994)
>       at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:123411)
>       at ViewContainerRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ViewContainerRef_.createComponent
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:130196)
>       at RouterOutlet.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.RouterOutlet.activateWith
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:154164)
>       at ActivateRoutes.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes
>   (/vendor.bundle.js:153303)
>       at /vendor.bundle.js:153254
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at resolvePromise (/polyfills.bundle.js:6299)
>       at resolvePromise (/polyfills.bundle.js:6270)
>       at /polyfills.bundle.js:6347
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (/polyfills.bundle.js:5953)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (/vendor.bundle.js:124002)
>       at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (/polyfills.bundle.js:5952)
>       at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (/polyfills.bundle.js:5720)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (/polyfills.bundle.js:6113)
>       at

My route configuration is looking like this:

```
const routes: Routes =  [
{
    path: '',
    component: FullLayoutComponent,
    children: []
}];

routes.push({ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent });
routes.push({ path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent });
routes.push({ path: 'recover', component: RecoverComponent });
routes.push({ path: 'userconfirmemail/:id/:confirmationCode', component: 
ConfirmEmailComponent });
routes.push({ path: 'userresetpassword/:id/:resetCode', component: 
ResetPasswordComponent });
routes.push({ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' });

routes[0].children.push({ path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', canActivate: 
[AuthGuard], pathMatch: 'full' });
routes[0].children.push({ path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
component: DashboardComponent });
routes[0].children.push({ path: 'user', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: 
UserOverviewComponent, data: { roles: [RoleRights.UsersView] } });
```

The error comes up on "recover" and "userconfirm" routes. And it just comes up, if no user is logged on.

When logging in and calling the route afterwords, it works. But there is no authguard in recover route.. So.. What the heck could be the problem?! Anyone?

Comment: Wither RecoverComponent or its template is not available, this error occurs in those cases.. Try removing those and see if it helps .

Comment: component is availaible. template too. it works, when i'm logged in, so i think, component and template are not the problem.

Comment: @Machine can you show your userconfirmeemail and userresetpassword component code. i want to see how you have handled id and confirmation parameter. make sure in ActivatedRoute params are same as id and resetCode

Comment: I now how to handle it:

this.model.UserId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.model.ConfirmationCode = this.route.snapshot.params['confirmationCode'];

RecoverComponent doesn't use any ideas and throws the same error. So I don't think, that any idea is the problem. Right?

Comment: @Machine this.model.UserId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'] || 0; check if this fix you error. make sure you are sending some value in id. i think you are sending undefined when user not login. so in your userconfirmation component add if condition and call your api only if id is not undefined

Comment: i'm sending correct ids. ids where interpreted correctly.
the problem appears at RecoverComponent too, which even does not handle any route parameters.
so again: ids are not the problem here.